# Payment method token is invalid when I create subscription in Braintree

Tags: python, payment-gateway, braintree

I want to create a subscription using Braintree using Python and JS.
But I get an error:

```
'errors': <braintree.errors.Errors object at 0xb0d157cc>, 'transaction': None, 'subscription': None, 'message': 'Payment method token is invalid.', 'credit_card_verification': None, 'merchant_account': None
```

**The way how I create token and subscription**

```
    token = braintree.ClientToken.generate({
        "customer_id": self.braintree_customer.id
    })

    create_subscriptions = braintree.Subscription.create({
        "payment_method_token": token,
        "plan_id": self.plan_id
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The Subscription needs a Payment Method Token, not a Client Token:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/client-token/generate

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/subscription/create#payment_method_token